# How can I convert a character variable (numbers with commas) to a numeric variable?

Tags: r

I did a survey in which I ask dog owners the starting age of a disease and many answers are 0,5 years (6 months), 2,5 years,... etc. R reads this vector (`dataframe$startage`) as a character. If I use the `as.numeric()` or `as.double()` function all the values with commas get `NA`. How can I prevent this from happening?
I tried with `dplyr` but couldn't find the correct function.

Comment: Try `as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", your_var))`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @julian, this keeps the values without turning them in NA but when I check with class(variable) it still gives me character.

Comment: actually it does work with another variable but not with this one...

Comment: Could you add ‘dput(data frame)’ and include it above?

Comment: dput(DF2$startage)
c("1", "0", "2", "1", "0", "NA", "1", "0,5", "1", "0", "0,5", 
"NA", "1", "1", "1,5", "1", "NA", "0,5", "0", "0", "8", "0", 
"0,5", "NA", "1", "NA", "NA", "2", "6", "1", "1,5", "0", "5", 
"3", "0", "5", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "3", "NA", "NA", "0", 
"NA", "0", "4", "NA", "NA", "0,5", "NA", "NA", "NA", "0,5", "NA", 
"10", "0,5", "NA", "0", "NA", "0,5", "0,5", "1", "NA", "0,5",  etc) but there are 1186 observations (responders) so it was too long.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the information on posting at the top of the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag page and provide reproducible input so we know exactly what the input looks like.
Assuming that you have the following then use `scan` .

```
x1 <- c("0,5", "2,5")
scan(text = x1, dec = ",", quiet = TRUE)
## [1] 0.5 2.5
```

This input variation works too:

```
x2 <- c("0,5 2,5")
scan(text = x2, dec = ",", quiet = TRUE)
## [1] 0.5 2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all commas with periods that can then be understood by `as.numeric()` :)

```
a <- c('0,3', '0,5')
b <- gsub(',','.',a)
c <- as.numeric(b)
c

[1] 0.3 0.5
```

Comment: thanks anyway but this gave all my values an NA, with or without comma's

Comment: As Julian mentioned, it's very helpful to include an example of your data so our answers are correct, otherwise we're just guessing what your exact problem is